# Probability question about number of ways to seat two boys and two girls in two rows which each have two desks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A room has $4$ desks configured as $2$ rows of $2$ desks each. There are $2$ boys and $2$ girls. If $A$ is the event that a boy is seated in desk 1 (upper left corner) and $B$ is the event that girls are seated in the same row, what are the probabilities for $A$ and $B$?

I understand for $P(A)$ is $$\frac{2C1 \cdot 3!}{4!}$$ because $1$ out of $2$ boys are seating at table 1 and there are $3$ tables left, so $3!$. And we divide it by total possible ways ($4!$).

Yet for $P(B)$, the answer says it's $$\frac{2(2!)(2!)}{4!}$$ but I do not understand where $2$ is from. Is it supposed to be $$\frac{2!2!}{4!}$$ because first $2!$ is for number of ways girls can be seated and second $2!$ is for number of ways boys can be seated?

Comment: but girls can be either in the front row or back and so we multiply by $2$

Comment: It makes sense when I think about it but I was wondering if there is any logical formula that I can apply to any other question like this.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  By the way, you can produce $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Revised answer after revised interpretation}$

It is simpler to compute probabilities directly

$P(A) =\dfrac{2}{4}\;\;\;\;$[There are $4$ claimants for the seat of which only $2$ *claimants* are "good"]

$P(B) = \dfrac13\;\;\;\;$[The first girl can be seated anywhere, the next one has only $1$ "good" *seat* out of $3$ remaining ]